# Is there a way to output something in a gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

It seems that `print`, `puts`, or `logger.info` doesn't work in an included gem. I was wondering if there was a workaround.

Comment: Could you provide more details? Are you trying to manually edit a gem with debug statements? Do you want to add some logging functionalities in your GEM?

Answer (score 1):

`RAILS_DEFAULT_LOGGER` is a global reference you can use in almost any context.

Answer (score 0):

A note for future: `RAILS_DEFAULT_LOGGER` had been deprecated in Rails 3.x+.

Now you can use:

```
Rails.logger.debug
```